# Need help reading Substrings in Files in C#?

Tags: c#, file, substring

So I created a subroutine to read some files... Here's the code:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + listBox1.Text + ".txt");

            foreach (string line in lines)
        {

            int posicion1 = line.IndexOf("|") + 1;
            int posicion2 = line.IndexOf("|", posicion1) + 1;
            int posicion3 = line.IndexOf("|", posicion2) + 1;
            int posicion4 = line.IndexOf("|", posicion3) + 1;


            data1 = line.Substring(0, posicion1 - 1);
            data2 = line.Substring(posicion1, posicion2 - posicion1 - 1);
            formacao = line.Substring(posicion2, posicion3 - posicion2 - 1);
            relatorio = line.Substring(posicion3, posicion4 - posicion3 -1);

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(data1, data2, formacao, relatorio);


        }
```

However, when it comes to adding the variable "relatorio" to the dataGridView, it just adds the ENTIRE line I have saved my variables on... Here's how I'm saving a line from my files for example:

28 de junho de 2017|28 de junho de 2017|fsdfsdfsd|Não

As you can see, I'm separating all of the variables with a "|".
Summing Up, the program works correctly except the variable "relatorio" which is just adding the ENTIRE line (28 de junho de 2017|28 de junho de 2017|fsdfsdfsd|Não) when is just supposed to add "Não".

Can someone help me out? Sorry if the question is not clear enough.

-- *UPDATE*

So i have tried to use this instead:

```
 foreach (string line in lines)
        {

            string[] _line = line.Split('|');
            string value1 = _line[0];
            string value2 = _line[1];
            string value3 = _line[2];
            string value4 = _line[3];
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(value1, value2, value3, value4);


        }
```

But STILL my program remains with the same mistake...
I'm starting to think that I'm not correctly saving my files but i really don't see anywhere i screwed up... The file remains the same type when i close the program:

28 de junho de 2017|28 de junho de 2017|fwfew|Não

Can anyone test this out if you have the time of course?

Comment: Why not just use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Answer (score 2):

The String class already has a [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var parts=line.Split('|');
dgv1.Rows.Add(parets[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
```

The various Split overloads allow you to use multiple separators and eliminate empty results

You should probably look at parsers like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). It can parse and map CSV data directly to objects, allow custom mappings and transformations, eg:

```
public class MyClass { public string Data1{get;set;} ...}

using(var reader=File.OpenText(csvPath))
{
    var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "|";
    var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>().ToList();
    dgv1.DataSource=records;
}
```

Or use LINQ:

```
    var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>().Where(it=>it.Data1 >=...).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `IndexOf`, you are making things a bit more complicated than they should be. You can just use the [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get your values:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
     string[] _line = line.Split('|');
     string value1 = _line[0];
     string value2 = _line[1];
     ...

     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(value1 , value2 , ...);
}
```